# How to display columns in cgridview which are not contained in any model?

Tags: yii, cgridview

I cannot display columns in cgridview which are not contained in any of the model's  virtual attribute

fnname function is in model1 (wherein pid ,mid ,expirydate are the property)

```
 ( fsp.pid = ".$this->pid." 
    AND fsp.mid=".$this->mid.
     )";
```

$this->pid is fk in model1 its belongs to model2 ......$this->mid is pk to model1 the cgridview doesnt display for this code as the value for $this->pid  $this->mid are null if i remove start to end it diplay the rest value

```
public function  fnname()
{
    $uid=Yii::app()->SESSION['mid'];
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    //start
    $post_table = Model1::model()->tableName();
    $post_count_sql = "(SELECT  datediff(fsp.expirydate,CURDATE())as daysleft
    from $post_table fsp
    WHERE ( fsp.pid = ".$this->pid." 
    AND fsp.mid=".$this->mid.
     )";

    $criteria->select = array(
    '*',
    $post_count_sql . " as daysleft",
);

    $criteria->compare('$post_count_sql', $this->daysleft);
    //end
    $criteria->condition='userid='.$userid;

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 2),
    ));
}
```

The error occurs

```
 SELECT  datediff(fsp.expirydate,CURDATE())as daysleft
     from tbl fsp
   WHERE ( fsp.pid = 
  AND fsp.mid=
 )
```

here fsp.pid and fsp.mid is blank

If i remove //start    //end line, the gridview displays

if i have this query then

```
     (SELECT datediff( fsp.expirydate, CURDATE( ) ) AS daysleft
FROM tbl1 fsp

) 
     Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *, (SELECT datediff( fsp.expirydate, CURDATE( ) ) AS daysleft
FROM tbl1 fsp

) as daysleft FROM `tbl1` `t` WHERE uid=3
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

the output must be like tihs

```
ptid   mid    daysleft   userid
1       1      30        3
2       1      10         3
1       10      1         3
```

ie., for userid 3 it should display all his records

```
   $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
//start
$post_table = Model1::model()->tableName();
$post_count_sql = "(SELECT  datediff(fsp.expirydate,CURDATE())as daysleft
from $post_table fsp
WHERE ( fsp.pid = ".$this->pid." 
AND fsp.mid=".$this->mid.
 )";

$criteria->select = array(
'*',
$post_count_sql . " as daysleft",
```

);

```
$criteria->compare('$post_count_sql', $this->daysleft);
//end
$criteria->condition='userid='.$userid;///line1
```

if i remove line one other user records are also shown which is not aloowed ..... am really confused

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: what is virtual column name here?

Comment: @Letmesee SELECT  datediff(fsp.expirydate,CURDATE())as daysleft
     from tbl fsp
   WHERE ( fsp.pid = 
  AND fsp.mid=
 )    ............  fsp.pid = 
  AND fsp.mid=........ there are no values for these

Comment: Do you want to use daysleft  in your gridview?

Comment: what are the values of $this->pid and $this->mid

Comment: empty value whereas both properties are of same model in which i assign them the select query its not assigin those values am

Comment: You have totally changed your question. Initially you asked how to display the virtual value from model in gridview. But now your asking another question after editing old one.

Comment: no its its the same question daysleft is not in db  $this->pid and $this->mid i dont know what wrong wit it .... hope u understood  my question ....... is there any solution

Comment: As per your new error, your query returned more than one row. make it as single row with some condition.

Comment: @kumar_v i have update my question see the last section ..... can you suggest some idea

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use daysleft  in your gridview, You have to declare in model as model variable

```
public $daysleft;
```

Then you can use in gridview as `$data->daysleft;`

Comment: fsp.pid = AND fsp.mid= should satisfy but the values are null

Comment: pid and mid is always empty? Or having some values?

Comment: ya its always empty empty value whereas both properties are of same model in which i assign them the select query its not assigin those values

Comment: i din get you you mean this code ? ...... this is the exception SELECT datediff(fsp.expirydate,CURDATE())as daysleft from tbl fsp WHERE ( fsp.pid = AND fsp.mid= )

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass the empty values for pid and mid?

Comment: obviously no how can i get any value if  empty assignment   i have values(pid,mid) in db i need is foreach this particular pid and mid in db shoul show me daysleft which is not a fiel in db

Comment: I asked where is pid and mid values set. You are not giving clear code and information regarding this. Then how can i answer properly? You need to check the pid and mid values and analyse why these two are empty.

Comment: pid and mid value are not set they are from this particular model1 ...... will it not assign then am assign this model1 value itself to those particular fsd.pid n fsd.mid ......... as well hv upadted content in my question please read

Comment: Now i understood your problem. May i know what is the $this->daysleft  Value? Is there any condition to check with days left?

Comment: it returns only one value with exception htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string array given ......... whereas ineed something like the output i have updated in the question

Comment: i think you no need to check the pid and mid in where condition.